Ratio of two diverging integrals
Consider the ratio:
$$
r = \frac{\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\, e^{-x^2 / 2a} x^2}{\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\, e^{-x^2 / 2a}}
$$

For $a > 0$ we have $r = a$ because after equal normalization of both integrals they become the Gaussian variance and $1$.
I am interested in the case of $a < 0$, where both integrals diverge, but I believe their ratio should be well-defined.
Possible guesses are $\infty,1,0$ and $a$, of course.


The bulk of both integrals is for large $x$, where the ratio between them is large.  So the limit is $\infty$

Are the integral limits in numerator and denominator the same? Are these integral limits positive or negative and/or close to zero?

@R.J.Mathar both are $\pm \infty$, would edit to clarify

I would say:  $\infty/\infty$ is undefined.  There is nothing you can do about it.

You can make sense of it by regularising your integrals. Introduce a cutoff $X$ so that:
$$
r(a,X) = \frac{\int_{-X}^Xx^2e^{-x^2/2a}dx}{\int_{-X}^Xe^{-x^2/2a}dx}
$$
which is now well defined for $a\in\mathbb R$. The idea is look at the limit $r(a,X\to+\infty)$. By integration by parts:
$$
\int_{-X}^Xx^2e^{-x^2/2a}dx = [-axe^{-x^2/2a}]_{-X}^X+a\int_{-X}^Xe^{-x^2/2a}dx
$$
so:
$$
\begin{align}
r(a,X) &= -\frac{2aXe^{-X^2/2a}}{\int_{-X}^Xe^{-x^2/2a}dx}+a \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{2a}Xe^{-X^2/2a}}{\sqrt\pi\text{erf}(X/\sqrt{2a})}+a \\
\end{align}
$$
For $a<0$ and $X\to+\infty$:
$$
r(a,X) \sim X^2
$$
so, $r(a<0) = +\infty$. In physical terms, $r$ is cutoff dependent. You'll need further cancellations to get a finite result. For example, in the same vein, you could suggestively claim that:
$$
\frac{\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x^2e^{-x^2/2a}dx}{\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2/2a}dx\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dx\right)^2} = 1
$$
and make it rigorous using the cutoff argument. In any case, you have a phase transition as $a$ crosses zero, due to the change of scaling in terms of the cutoff $X$.
Another natural answer would be to take the analytic continuation so you still have $r(a)= a$. This is tantamount to disregarding the first term which is cutoff dependent and keeping only the cutoff dependent term. It could be useful if you are interested in quantities where the leading order terms cancel additively.
